# Using CASE for both field and order sorting in an ORDER BY clause with IN statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, prisma

i'm currently working in Prisma and trying to do sort with raw sql query, but i can't achive this. I'm using variables for both field name and sorting order, i've also want to include IN statement to just shortening the amount of code (without multiple WHEN statement) and ELSE statement for default value:

```
const users = await prisma.$queryRaw<User[]>(
        `
        SELECT * FROM "Users"
        ORDER BY 
            CASE WHEN $1 IN ('name','surname') THEN $1 ELSE 'id' END
            CASE WHEN $2 IN ('ASC','DESC') THEN $2 ELSE 'ASC' END
        `,
        sort?.fieldName || 'name',
        sort?.order || 'ASC'
    )
```

I'm getting this error when executing this lines of code:

```
 "code": "P2010",
          "clientVersion": "2.17.0",
          "meta": {
            "code": "42601",
            "message": "db error: ERROR: syntax error at or near \"CASE\""
          },
          "stacktrace": [
            "Error: ",
            "Invalid `prisma.queryRaw()` invocation:",
            "",
            "",
            "  Raw query failed. Code: `42601`. Message: `db error: ERROR: syntax error at or near \"CASE\"`",
            "    at cb (/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:78689:17)",
            "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)"
          ],
          "message": "\nInvalid `prisma.queryRaw()` invocation:\n\n\n  Raw query failed. Code: `42601`. Message: `db error: ERROR: syntax error at or near \"CASE\"`",
```

I was trying to achive this with a lot of combination with commas, brackets in a lot of variants but at best algorithm was just not sort records.

I've also executing similiar command directly on database (without params but with real value) but with the same result.

#### EDIT 1

I've prepare SQL query for test purposes, but without parameters (I don't know how to use it in raw SQL).

```
SELECT * FROM "Users"
        ORDER BY 
            CASE WHEN 'name' IN ('name','surname') THEN 'name' ELSE 'id' END,
            CASE WHEN 'DESC' IN ('ASC','DESC') THEN 'DESC' ELSE 'ASC' END
```

Above code is executing properly, but still don't sorting in correct way.

Comment: You need a comma before the second case expression.

Comment: So you mean this - `THEN $1 ELSE 'id' END, .....` ?

Comment: It's correctly executing but when i pass 'name' to sorting field it's still sorting by id. So it looks like query choose ELSE statement.

Comment: Please retrieve the effective SQL that is being executed and add it to the question. Your code may be producing the wrong SQL query.

Comment: I've added SQL query to the quesion

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here, but I don't think the SQL you're trying is going to do what you think it will. Are you trying to sort by a column called "name" when  some name_category is in '(name, surname)' and by id otherwise? The two case statements just always evaluate to a constant in the second part. Maybe you could better explain what you're trying to do rather than the SQL you're trying to use to do it.

Comment: "Are you trying to sort by a column called "name" when some name_category is in '(name, surname)' and by id otherwise?", yeah bro. But you have to remember that i'm using this in my code, so instead of static "name" it will be some field name from variable, so it doesn't always be a static variable. Do you understand my issue ? I've just want to run this query correctly - without errors and just working sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const users = await prisma.$queryRaw<User[]>(
        `
        SELECT * FROM "Users"
        ORDER BY 
            CASE WHEN $1 = 'true' THEN
                CASE $2 WHEN 'name' THEN u.name
                WHEN 'surname' THEN u.surname
                ELSE u.id::varchar END
            END DESC,
            CASE WHEN $1 = 'false' THEN
                CASE $2 WHEN 'name' THEN u.name 
                WHEN 'surname' THEN u.surname
                ELSE u.id::varchar END
            END ASC
        `,
       sort?.order === 'DESC' ? 'true' : 'false',
       sort?.fieldName || 'id'
    )
```

This query works for me, unfortunately i don't know how to use it with `IN` statement.
`u.id::varchar` is use because `CASE` statement must have one type return, `ID` field is `Int`, so i change type to `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a programming language (is this PHP?) to create your SQL statement from your variables. A resulting SQL may either look like this (if your variables contain single quotes):

```
SELECT * FROM "Users"
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN 'name' IN ('name','surname') THEN 'name' ELSE 'id' END,
    CASE WHEN 'DESC' IN ('ASC','DESC') THEN 'DESC' ELSE 'ASC' END
```

... or like this (if your variables don't contain single quotes):

```
SELECT * FROM "Users"
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN name IN ('name','surname') THEN name ELSE id END,
    CASE WHEN DESC IN ('ASC','DESC') THEN DESC ELSE 'ASC' END
```

The first query does no sorting at all. You select the rows by the constant strings 'name' and 'DESC'. As the strings are the same for every row, no sorting takes place.

The scond query fails with an error. The `ORDER BY` clause becomes essentially `ORDER BY name, DESC`, but there is no column `DESC` in your table. You cannot remove the comma either, because then you have an invalid `CASE` expression. The main problem here: The result of a `CASE` expression cannot be a SQL keyword.

Two options:

**OPTION 1:** Build the query completely with your programming language. Something along the lines of:

```
$column = ($1 = "name" or $1 = "surname") ? $1 : "id";
$order = ($2 = "DESC") ? "DESC" : "ASC";
$query = `SELECT * FROM "Users" ORDER BY $column $order`;
```

**OPTION 2:** Have your SQL deal with this:

```
$query = `
  SELECT * FROM "Users" 
  ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN '$2' = 'DESC' THEN
      CASE WHEN '$1' = 'name' THEN name
           WHEN '$1' = 'surname' THEN surname
           ELSE id
      END
    ELSE
      ''
    END DESC,
    CASE WHEN '$2' <> 'DESC' THEN
      CASE WHEN '$1' = 'name' THEN name
           WHEN '$1' = 'surname' THEN surname
           ELSE id
      END
    ELSE
      ''
    END ASC
  `;
```

There is one last problem. The result in a `CASE` expression must be of one type. I suppose that `name` and `surname` are strings, so if `id` is numeric, then you must convert it into a string. E.g. replace `id` by `TO_CHAR(id, '000000000000000000')`.

Comment: I'm using NodeJS and ORM called Prisma

Comment: An ORM where you write the SQL statements yourself? Anyway, adapt one of my solutions to your environment. This shouldn't be too much of a difference.

Comment: Example you provide, donesn't working in SQL and in code.

Comment: I've tried this query on raw database, by changing parameters '$1' and '$2' to real values, because postgres donesn't have params. But it still doesn't working.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/codemasternode/9eff492b5066a70c70e388c1c757d5f8

Comment: The SQL solution doesn't work for $1 that represent no columns in the table. Otherwise it does. I'll fix this, but it's a complicated solution anyway. The code solution is much more readable in my opinion.

Comment: Original SQL answer: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=aa12db320aebac04b51249e4eb3b5a79. Fixed SQL: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3a92cbe75d3c1ba7f5f6dedcd684d674

Comment: And here is your try: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f8fa5180f6d872e420be6b71982dd71b. As proposed I am getting the error that types don't match, because the ID is numeric in my example. By making it a string column, I don't get the error anymore: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6d83a73ead29ed77f946607bf447bdf2

Comment: Thanks, it's working but only in raw SQL, when it comes to prisma, unfortunately no.